# Constructing parametric equation for $x=3z\cos(\ln z)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, parametric

I was trying to transform this $$x=3z\cos(\ln z)$$ in parametric form: $$x=x(t)$$ $$z=z(t).$$ 
To this end I made a substitution $\ln{z}=t$ and I got: $$x=3{e^t}\cos(t)$$ $$z=e^t$$ $$t\in (-\infty,\infty)$$ 
But the graphs of initial equation and the resultant one are completely different. Please show me my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to parametrize this is by putting $z = t$, then $x = 3t \cos \ln t$, $t \in (-\infty, \, \infty )$.

Comment: Yes, ok. But I dont understand why my option doesnt work.

Comment: @blitzar787 $e^t$ is strictly positive, so you lose the negative part of the parameter domain. Think of it as substituting $t = x^2$; you lose part of the parametrization.

Comment: thx, I thought about it, but I noticed that we have $lnz$ which domain is also strictly positive, thats why I thought it was not a problem. Could you comment on this and show me my mistake?